# System call open C can't print file content if the file is not opened as sudo

Tags: c, file, operating-system, root, system-calls

So I create a new file:

```
 fd = open("tester.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR);
```

then using the system call write I add some info to it. But when I try to read the info from the file, it can't be made. Using the **terminal** I found out, that the only way to open the file is to use **sudo** and the **content is successfully written**. However, my program can't be root. So, how do I open the file, write some content to it and without closing the C program output the file.

Comment: How exactly did you find out that you need to use sudo?  What specifically did you find to reach that conclusion?

Comment: cat filename does't open file but sudo cat filename does

Comment: @KarinaK because first you craeted file without permission, now once delete file manually using rm command and then again execute your program

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing to specify the file mode as third argument to the creating open call; try the following:

```
fd = open("tester.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644);
```

Then, the file should be created with mode `-rw-r--r--`, so your own user can open it for reading and writing. Otherwise, it might end up with some random permission, i.e. `---------`, and only root can open this for reading (without chmodding it, at least).

Comment: I get the following error: tail: error writing 'standard output': Bad address

Comment: @KarinaK Now, where does `tail` come into play?

Comment: just text from the perror, the error itself is Bad address

Comment: that means that OP didn't include the prototype for `open` ??

Comment: @KarinaK I do not see a perror() above, perhaps you should specify the code in a bigger context.

Answer (score 3):

whenever you are using O_CREAT flag in open() system call, you should explicitly provide the permission. man page of open() says

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

**mode** specifies the permissions to use in case a new file is cre‐ated.  This argument must be supplied when **O_CREAT** is  specified in  flags;  if  O_CREAT  is not specified, then mode is **ignored**.

So modify above line as

```
  fd = open("tester.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0664 );
```

I hope it will clear your doubts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept the other answer because Karim was first.

Comment: yup @KarinaK your welcome, just 5 minutes late !! I came just now only from work